Exercise - Random Walk, Implement clumsiness
So, the exercise is centered around a game that will tell in which step of a building you will be. You throw a die 100x and if the number is less than or equal to 2, you fall one step (if you are in step 0, you will stay in step 0), if it is higher than 2 and less than or equal to 5, you climb one step. If the number is 6, you throw the die again and will climb the resulting number of steps.
The following code simulates this game 20x. The exercise also says the following: "There's still something we forgot
! You're a bit clumsy and you have a 0.5% chance of falling down. That calls for another random number generation
. Basically, you can generate a random float between 0 and 1. If this value is less than or equal to 0.005, you should reset step to 0". I didn't understand this last part, and will show the code that solves the exercise for clarification.

# clear the plot so it doesn't get cluttered if you run this many times
plt.clf()
# Simulate random walk 20 times
all_walks = []
for i in range(20) :
    random_walk = [0]
    for x in range(100) :
        step = random_walk[-1]
        dice = np.random.randint(1,7)
        if dice <= 2:
            step = max(0, step - 1)
        elif dice <= 5:
            step = step + 1
        else:
            step = step + np.random.randint(1,7)

        # Implement clumsiness
        if np.random.rand() <= 0.005 :
            step = 0

        random_walk.append(step)
    all_walks.append(random_walk)

# Create and plot np_aw_t
np_aw_t = np.transpose(np.array(all_walks))
plt.plot(np_aw_t)
plt.show()```



What's your question?

Make sure your triple backticks are on their own separate lines. Code on the same line as the first set gets ignored, and if the second set is not in its own line, it doesn't get processed at all.

For the last part, there is a 0.5% chance of falling, which means you need to 'roll a dice' and see if you hit the 0.5% jackpot. If you do, reset your step to zero.
The question indicates that this may happen every time so you need to run it in every step, after rolling the dice. You can't just fall and walk right after, so it's walk then fall.
One way of doing this is shown in the answer
if np.random.rand() <= 0.005:
    step = 0

np.random.rand() generates a float from 0.0 to 1.0.
To extract the 0.5% probability, you need to specify a range of values to represent that 0.5% probability and check if the generated value falls in the range.
It's just like how you represent the probability of 50% by choosing one of the heads or tails.
In this case, the answer chooses the range 0.000 to 0.005, and checks if the result falls in the range by doing (if np.random.rand() <= 0.005)
For your understanding, you can also choose 0.095 to 1.000 to represent the 0.5% probability. In that case, you would do
if np.random.rand() >= 0.095:
    step = 0

which would result in the same probability

Electron X, the question is asking for 0.5%, not 5%.

@lastchance can't believe I missed it, thank you

Oh, now I understand. My doubt was more to the side of interpretation. Now, I see that this 0.05% chance of falling down is something in addition to the initial throw of the die.
